# Connect node with Oracle

Tags: oracle, node.js

I need to connect to oracle db and fetch some data through node. 
Is there any driver available to connect node with oracle? Is this possible?

Found many links to this question in stackoverflow, but none had the updated answers. Any idea? Please help.

Answer (score 2):

I know this post is already few months old, but this one is the official Oracle driver for NodeJS:
https://github.com/oracle/node-oracledb

Link on npm:
https://www.npmjs.com/package/oracledb

I have used it for a few months now for simple cases and it works really fine.
Community is active so they are adding new features on a regular basis.

Answer (score 0):

Whenever in doubt consult [NPM](http://npmjs.org). For oracle specific node module check [oracle module](https://npmjs.org/package/oracle)
 and [db-oracle module](https://npmjs.org/package/db-oracle)

Comment: Tried that. I am getting a error like ERROR: You appear to not be running in a Visual Studio prompt.
npm ERR! oracle@0.1.3 install: `node mnm.js build` when installing "npm install oracle" Please help

Comment: start googling for the answers. In your case you need to run vcvars.bat from Visual Studio installation Director